# Simplified Java 8 Stream map entity to model

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two lists in Java, a list of models that I am receiving via a restful endpoint and a list of entities from my database. I am looping through all of the entities and updating the models with the appropriate ID generated after an insert. I need to do it this way because the model has other information that is not in the entity that I need to use later.

This is what I am doing now and it works:

```java
savedUserEntities.stream()
       .map(x ->
               uploadUserList.stream()
                       .filter(i -> x.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(i.getUsername()))
                       .peek(i -> i.setId(x.getId()))
                       .findFirst()
                       .orElse(null))
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I feel like it could be a little cleaner. Basically I am looping through the entities, finding the matching model, updating the model with the ID from the entity or setting it to null if there is no match, filtering out the resultant nulls, and then returning the updated models. Is there a cleaner way to do this same thing?

Edit:

This is my entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String userName;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Long organizationId;

private Long updatedDate;
private Long createdDate;
private Long userInactiveDate;
private Long departmentId;
private String batchId;
private Long tempPasswordExpiresDate;
```

This is my model:

```
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String username;
private Long department;
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = NestedDeserializer.class)
private List<Permission> permissions;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class Permission {
    private long locationId;
    private long roleId;
    private boolean all;
    private boolean assigned;
    private boolean unassigned;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for using the peek?

Comment: If you were using Java 9+, you could eliminate the `.orElse(null)` and change the `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to `.flatMap(Optional::stream)`

Comment: *I am looping through all of the entities and updating the models* ... don't prefer streams for such mutation. Also, the question would be in much cleaner state if you could actually share the entities with the attributes in use.

Comment: @Michal I am using peek to add the ID to the element. I filter first and then peek to add the ID.

Comment: @Jacob, unfortunately I am limited to Java 8.

Comment: @nullpointer, You are right. I am returning a new list and updating the old list too. What should I do to add the ID without mutating the original?

Comment: @Gremash Well to answer that, one would need help in understanding what is it that's making you do that? What actually is the problem statement you're trying to solve and is there no other way out? Why would you want to update a list while iterating over it to find if some content there matches with another list based on a condition and at the same time ensure that another list is updated as well? Looks overly complicated. Just imagine a use case where your inner `filter` is applicable for two objects, you would update both of them and still select one of them to be mapped afterward.

Comment: I am little tired but I am still not getting the peek(). Perhaps the peek() is done in order to be able to do findFirst() afterwards? Would not something like filter().findFirst().map(...).orElse(null) do? The ... in map() would do a copy of the model + set the id. That would solve the issue raised by @nullpointer (updating data in stream).

Comment: @nullpointer Basically, I am taking the list of models, converting them to entities to insert them to that DB. I then need to update my models with the IDs so I can pass the data through the process as there are some unique business requirements for me to do so.

Comment: @Michal That makes sense and is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your code does the following:

- for each Saved User Entity
- map it to a single element within UploadUser List, where the username matches, case-insensitively
- set id of found UploadUser to id of SavedUserEntity
- collect found UploadUsers into list.

`uploadUserList.stream()` looks suspicious to me, since it traverses the uploadUserList *for each element of `savedUserEntities`*. Assuming that the uploadUserList does not change, it might be a waste of time. Instead of traversing the list, you might instead want to lookup the element in a map.

Also, the Streams documentation states that the `peek` method exists mainly to support debugging, so I'm holding back a little to actually use `peek`.

I would suggest something like this:

We first build a Map which associates a username to an UploadUser. If multiple usernames are found, use the first one (the `left` one).

```
Map<String, UploadUser> uploadUserMap = uploadUserList.stream()
    .map(t -> new SimpleEntry<>(t.getUserName().toLowerCase(), t))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (left, right) -> left));
```

Then we walk over the SavedUserEntries and check if there is a corresponding UploadUser (by case-insensitive username). If so, then set id and map the current SavedUserEntry to the UploadUser.
Finally, collect results.

```
List<UploadUser> uploadUsers = savedUserEntities.stream()
    .filter(t -> uploadUserMap.containsKey(t.getUserName().toLowerCase()))
    .map(t -> {
        UploadUser uploadUser = uploadUserMap.get(t.getUserName().toLowerCase());
        uploadUser.setId(t.getId());
        return uploadUser;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, it's not entirely clear to me why you should pick a single UploadUser by their username and assign the id of the savedUserEntity to it, discarding other UploadUsers with the same username (do they exist?).

Also,

> updating the model with the ID from the entity or setting it to null if there is no match

You are not setting anything to `null`. Your filter discards all UploadUsers without a match, so `i -> i.setId(x.getId())` is only ever executed when there *is* a match.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense. Yes, the uploaded users will be unique so I don't have to worry about subsequent matching usernames.